# How to tell Eclipse to stop moving my curly brace backwards

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, curly-braces, curly-brackets

I recently installed Eclipse (Helios Release) PDT and am trying to set the preferences to my project's style of code formatting.

I have gone into...

Eclipse PDT > Window > Preferences > PHP > Editor > Typing

...and unchecked all options.

I have also gone to:

Eclipse PDT > Window > Preferences > PHP > Editor > Templates

...and edited the 'Function Statement' template to look like this:

```
function ${function_name}() 
    {
    ${cursor};
    }
```

..and edited the 'class statement' template to look like this

```
class ${class_name}
    {
    function ${function_name}() 
            {
            ${cursor};
            }
    }
```

---

Now, back in the PHP editor, I am trying to write a method in the format like:

```
protected function testMethod()
    {
    return 'Hello'; 
    }
```

In order to do this. First I write:

```
protected function testMethod()
```

Then, I hit return and the cursor lands under the 'p' or protected. Which is OK I spose:

```
protected function testMethod()
|
```

Then, I hit TAB and the cursor moves forward to where I'd like my opening curly brace to be (as expected):

```
protected function testMethod()
    |
```

-- The problem: --

Then, as soon as I type my curly brace, Eclipse moves it backwards to end up under the 'p':

```
protected function testMethod()
{
```

So, each time I type an opening curly brace I have to go back and move it forward again to where I wanted it:

```
protected function testMethod()
    {
```

Then I carry on.

Which part of Eclipse is responsible for this behaviour and how can I stop Eclipse from moving the curly brace backwards?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Updates in response to suggestions:**

I have gone into...

Eclipse PDT > Window > Preferences > PHP > Editor

and unchecked both:

- Smart caret positioning at line start and end

  and
- Smart caret positioning in PHP names

Thanks for the suggestion [Victor Nitu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10005577/205814), but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall the UI & prefs back in the Helios, but as I can see in Indigo, I have the following setting:

`PHP -> Editor: Smart caret positioning at line end (chackbox)`

Let me know if it works.

*LE: Confirmed as not working in Indigo either. I'll be back if I find something.*

Comment: Thanks. I have that setting in Helios and have turned it off too. it did not seem to stop the probs. I'll update the question.

Comment: I am browsing the user setting in Eclipse right now, still no answer, and I begin to suspect this is due to an Eclipse bug or misfeature. Going to try some internal files soon, if any.

Comment: I also suspect this is a Java editor feature, which has broken during the PDT porting. Other Java programmers complain about it too: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109681

Comment: Ahaa!. Thanks for that. A quick skim of [this bug comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=117866#c4) makes me guess the fix is something to do with `AbstractTextEditor.Navigation.SmartHomeEnd=true`. I will have a play with it later today.

Comment: I searched my Ecplipse programme directory for 'AbstractTextEditor.Navigation.SmartHomeEnd' or 'SmartHomeEnd' and nothing found. Oh well -its not a config option I can alter myself w/o knowing a bit more about java.

Comment: I grepped the eclipse dirs multiple times, all I found were some Java binaries... until now